# Pass this to jquery on() function with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How pass this from function fun into jquery on() function?
Use this.panel in $(...).on(...) function.

During writing this question, i found one answer with on(..., data, ...), but I'm interested if there are others, as I spend some time searching for the answer.
Also as I searched stack's topics with similar questions, but I didn't find or saw similar answer, so I save it here in a case I would forgot it.

```
//Wrong code
function funWrong(selector) {
  this.selector = selector;
  this.panel = "#panel";

  $(selector).on("click", "a", function() {    
    $(this).addClass("w3-green"); //this is clicked link
    $(this.panel).addClass("w3-red"); //this is wrong
  });
}

//Working code:
function funOk(selector) {
  this.selector = selector;
  this.panel = "#panel";

  $(selector).on("click", "a", alias = this.panel, function() {    
    $(this).addClass("w3-green"); //this is clicked link
    $(alias).addClass("w3-red");
  });
}

//Use:
$(document).ready( function() {
  var f = new funWrong('#selector');
  var f = new funOk('#selector');
});
```

Comment: Since you arent using your functions as constructor functions, ie not doing `new funWrong()`, `this` directly in your functions is going to refer to the global object, in case of browsers the `window` object

Comment: New was just missed in this simplified function.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use an arrow function so that the `this` context from the outer scope is preserved, and use the `event.target` inside the click handler to get a reference to the clicked element:

```
$(selector).on("click", "a", (event) => {    
  $(event.target).addClass("w3-green");
  $(this.panel).addClass("w3-red");
});
```